# Swift - attributedString to HTML, <img src=.... is missing in ios 9

Tags: nsattributedstring

after I converted attributedString to HTML including some image source everything is fine in iOS 10 like :

`<p class="p3"><span class="s1"><img src="file:///Attachment.png" alt="Attachment.png"></span></p>`

but the `<img src=...` segment is missing if the app run on iOS 9:
`<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span></p>`

does anyone know why？

Comment: It seems that it is omitted (NSAttributedString to HTML). You would have to add it yourself.